# How to read in other class from isolated storage?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can I read a setting in MainPage.xaml/.cs ?

I use this [setting sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx#BKMK_Common) but I dont have accces to/from other class.

For example: In MainPage.xaml we have TextBlock, in SettingsWithoutConfirmation.xaml we have TextBox, How TextBlock can read this string from TextBox (and also save this to isolated storage) ?

I am newbie, please be gentle ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understood your question. 
In any xaml page, you can use the following to access settings that have been stored in isolated storage:

```
var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
if( settings.Contains("name") ) {
    //the value is available here
}

//to store a value permanently
settings["name"] = "New Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Save data to settings:

```
var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
settings.Add("myemail", "support@gmail.com");
```

Get data from settings:

```
var location = settings["myemail"].ToString();
settings["myemail"] = "support@gmail.com";
```